# How to import oracle databse into postgres with dbLink

Tags: oracle, postgresql, oracle11g, data-migration, dblink

I have postgres database on server A & oracle database on server B.

I would like to import the data of oracle to postgres using dbLink.

I have achieved this for Postgres to Postgres database, but now I would like to do this with oracle.

So 
I have achived postgres to postgres migration with following command.

```
SELECT realestate.address, realestate.parcel, s.sale_year, s.sale_amount, 
        FROM realestate INNER JOIN 
                dblink('dbname=dbdelv port=5432 host=someserver 
                user=user password=pwd',
                'SELECT parcel_id, sale_year, 
                    sale_amount FROM parcel_sales')
            AS s(parcel_id char(10),sale_year int, sale_amount int)
             ON realestate.parcel_id = s.parcel_id;
```

How can I do the same for oracle? and what will be db Link?

Answer (score 1):

`dblink` is for PostgreSQL only, it won't be able to connect to Oracle.

But you can use something that is even simpler, [`oracle_fdw`](http://laurenz.github.io/oracle_fdw/), which is a [foreign data wrapper](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-foreign-data.html) for Oracle.

Download the code and follow the [README](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw/master/README.oracle_fdw) to compile and install `oracle_fdw`.

Once you have created a [foreign server](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createserver.html) and a [user mapping](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createusermapping.html), you can [create a foreign table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createforeigntable.html) that will look and feel just like a normal PostgreSQL table, but the data reside in Oracle. You can use it in queries with joins like the one you showed in your question.